# how to test overloaded function in truffle?

Tags: web3js, truffle, testing, truffle-test

I recently upgraded truffle to the newest version. Now it does not automatically detect overloaded functions anymore. Before, I could just do the following:

```js
await contract.function({
  from: accounts[0],
  value: web3.utils.toWei("0.5", "Ether")
});

await contract.function(param1, param2, {
  from: accounts[0],
  value: web3.utils.toWei("0.5", "Ether")
});
```

Now it seems that I have to specify the parameters in a syntax like the following:

```js
await contract.function['uint256', 'uint256'](param1, param2, {
  from: accounts[0],
  value: web3.utils.toWei("0.5", "Ether")
});
```

But how can I declare the first function version without parameters? Doing this: `contract.function[''](...)` produces the error `contract.function is not a function`. Not declaring anything via `[]` produces the same error as well.

Also the parameters for the overloaded functions are two arrays. One `address[]` array and one `uint256[]` array. I already tried:

```js
contract.function["address[]", "uint256[]"](addressList, uintList, {...})
```

which doesn't work. It produces the same error.

I also didn't find any information about this in the truffle documentation.

Comment: Please post your contract.

Comment: What do you get from `$ truffle version` ?

Comment: Truffle version returns
```Truffle v5.0.0-next.26 (core: 5.0.0-beta.2)
Solidity - 0.5.4 (solc-js)
Node v8.11.4
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you upgrade to the latest version of Truffle, and then check out these release notes on overloaded functions: https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/releases/tag/v5.0.0#user-content-what-s-new-in-truffle-v5-interacting-with-your-contracts-overloaded-solidity-functions

I hope that helps a little!

Answer (score 0):

Solution (Truffle 5.0.0+):

```
const example = await Example.deployed();
example.methods['setValue(uint256)'](123);
example.methods['setValue(uint256,uint256)'](11, 55);
```