# How to call an overloaded function in Truffle with ABIEncoderV2?

Tags: truffle, truffle-contract, truffle-test, abiencoderv2

How do you call an overloaded function in Truffle when passing a struct using `pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;`?

```
contract MyContract {

  struct MyStruct {
      address param1;
      address param2;
      address param3;
  }

  function init(address owner) public {}

  function init(MyStruct memory myStruct) public {}
}
```

Calling `MyContract.init(myStruct)` tries to call the first init function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Related to [how to test overloaded function in truffle?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/67651/how-to-test-overloaded-function-in-truffle), but slightly different with passing a struct. The solution is simple:

```
MyContract.methods['init((address,address,address))'](myStruct)
```

Comment: I'm getting the error that above is not a function. I've tried both your way and the one in the link. I'm using `Truffle v5.3.14` and `Web3.js v1.4.0`

Comment: You adapted the code to your own contract function? Try `console.log({ MyContract })` to see which functions are available.