# Two identical functions inside a truffle migration

Tags: solidity, truffle, javascript, truffle-migration

The contract VestingWallet.sol from OpenZeppelin have two functions with the same name "vestedAmount", but different parameters to call a particular function.

The first one:

```
   function vestedAmount(uint64 timestamp) public view virtual returns (uint256) {
   return _vestingSchedule(address(this).balance + released(), timestamp);
   }
```

Second:

```
   function vestedAmount(address token, uint64 timestamp) public view virtual returns 
   (uint256) {
   return _vestingSchedule(IERC20(token).balanceOf(address(this)) + released(token), 
   timestamp);
   }
```

I'm writing a truffle migration file to see how tokens vests after one month, for example.

```
const timestamp_Start = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
const oneMonthLaterTimestamp = timestamp_Start + 30 * 24 * 60 * 60;
console.log("Vested amount after 1 month:", await myToken.vestedAmount(myToken.address, oneMonthLaterTimestamp));
```

It always ends with a failure:

```
Error: value out-of-bounds (argument="timestamp", value="0x00000000000000000000000018E1Def9870DFbDB0CF4E94440104E39393B53A2", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=abi/5.6.4)
```

And so on. I'm assuming that truffle calls the first one vestedAmount function and not seeing the second with different parameters, because if I locally change the name of the function to different - it gives the correct output. How do I implement this right if I want to call the second without changing the name of the function or without commenting selection of the first one function?

Comment: Check if the solution works in your case https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/84117/how-to-call-an-overloaded-function-in-truffle-with-abiencoderv2.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the link, need to refer to the overloaded function, by its key in contract.methods. In my case:

```
console.log("Vested amount after 1 month:", 
    BigInt(await 
        VestingWallet.methods['vestedAmount(address,uint64)'](
            myToken.address, 
            oneMonthLaterTimestamp
        )
    )
);
```